Math requirements for understanding the theory of diffusion probabilistic model
I'm currently computer science major student, with concentration on Artificial Intelligence. Recently, I found that the topic of diffusion model interests me a lot and I started to learn its application and theory by reading some papers myself.
However, as I deepen my knowledge in diffusion model, I found that some papers use "Stochastic Differential Equation" to describe the diffusion process and the reverse process in diffusion model which I've never learnt before (Score-Based Generative Modeling through Stochastic Differential Equations (Song. et al.) for example).
I also tried to learn SDE by myself. However, I found that I still need to learn real analysis, measure theory and stochastic process so I could really understand what SDE is doing. With some basic calculations, I need at least one-year to finish all these courses from the math department in my school.
I was wondering if I just want to know the connections between diffusion model and SDE, do I really need to learn all these from scratch or is there another way that I could grasp these content in some months ? If that's not the case, I would like to know what's the minimum content that I have to study in these three subjects for building the foundation of SDE. And also, how important the theoretical background of diffusion model is for a researcher who wants to do research about diffusion model.
Thanks in advance !
